# Replace a multiline pattern using Perl, sed, awk

Tags: bash, perl, unix, awk, sed

I need to concatenate multiple JSON files, so

```
        ...
        "tag" : "description"
    }
]
[
    {
        "tag" : "description"
        ...
```

into this :

```
    ...
    "tag" : "description"
},
{
    "tag" : "description"
    ...
```

So I need to replace the pattern `] [` with `,`, but the new line character makes me crazy...

I used several methods, I list some of them:

- **sed**

  ```
   sed -i '/]/,/[/{s/./,/g}' file.json
  ```

  but I get this error:

  ```
  sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated address regex
  ```
- I tried to delete all the newlines
  [following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

  ```
  sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.json
  ```

  and the output file has "^M". Although I modified this file in unix, I used the dos2unix command on this file but nothing happens. I tried then to include the special character "^M" on the search but with worse results
- **Perl**
  (as proposed [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/search-and-replace-multi-line-string.html))

  ```
  perl -i -0pe 's/]\n[/\n,/' file.json
  ```

  but I get this error:

  ```
  Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/]\n[ <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
  ```

Comment: Is direct string manipulation your only option? Why not parse the JSON in every file and write out the result also processed by the perl-core JSON module?

Comment: I probably understand your question wrong, but: Is the content of your first example lines the result of your own doing ('I would like to concatenate several JSON files.') or already a given fact in one of these files? If it's the latter, please ignore my first comment.

Comment: Where is the `][` between JSON objects coming from? In other words, how are you currently combining the files?

Comment: @SREagle 
Sorry I think the moderators cut my question. The **...}][{ ..** is the results of the concatenation of the 2 json files. Then, SREagle, your proposition is a possibility but I think the problem is still there with the last file to concatenate

Comment: @buondi: Did you try to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (that is designed to deal with json files)? This command-line should suffice: `jq -c -s -r '[.[]|.[]]' file.json > result.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a better way to combine multiple JSON files is to parse them all, combine the parsed data structure, and reencode the result. Simply changing all occurrences of `][` to a comma `,` may alter data instead of markup

sed is a minimal program that will operate only on a single line of a file at a time. Perl encompasses everything that sed or awk will do and a huge amount more besides, so I suggest you stick with it

To change all `]...[` pairs in `file.json` (possibly separated by whitespace) to a single comma, use this

```
perl -0777 -pe "s/\]\s*\[/,/g" file.json > file2.json
```

The `-0` option specifies an octal line separator, and giving it the value 777 makes perl read the entire file at once

One-liners are famously unintelligible, and I always prefer a proper program file, which would look like this

#### join_brackets.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <>;
}

$data =~ s/ \] \s* \[ /,/gx;

print $data;
```

and you would run it as

```
perl join_brackets.pl file.json > joined.json
```

Answer (score 2):

> *I would like to concatenate several JSON files.*

If I understand correctly, you have something like the following (where letters represent valid JSON values):

```
to_combine/file1.json: [a,b,c]
to_combine/file2.json: [d,e,f]
```

And from that, you want the following:

```
combined.json: [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

You can use the following to achieve this:

```
perl -MJSON::XS -0777ne'
   push @data, @{ decode_json($_) };
   END { print encode_json(\@data); }
' to_combine/*.json >combined.json
```

---

As for the problem with your Perl solution:

1. `[` has a special meaning in regex patterns. You need to escape it.
2. You only perform one replacement.
3. `-0` doesn't actually turn on slurp mode. Use `-0777`.
4. You place the comma after the newline, when it would be nicer before the newline.

Fix:

```
cat to_combine/*.json | perl -0777pe's/\]\n\[/,\n/g' >combined.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with example in your question.

```
$ sed -rn '
    1{$!N;$!N}
    $!N
    /\s*}\s*\n\s*]\s*\n\s*\[\s*\n\s*\{\s*/M { 
        s//\},\n\{/
        $!N;$!N 
    }
    P;D
' file
        ...
        "tag" : "description"
},
{
        "tag" : "description"
        ...
        ...
        "tag" : "description"
},
{
        "tag" : "description"
        ...
```